# Group rings decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, group-rings

Let $G$ be a group with $|G| = 8$.

By the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem, $\mathbb{C}G$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of matrix rings over division rings. What are the possible choices for a decomposition?

Now, I know the dimensions on each side must be equal, so are the only possibilities $\mathbb{C}^{(8)}$, $M_2({\mathbb{C}}) \oplus M_2({\mathbb{C}}) $, $M_2({\mathbb{C}}) \oplus \mathbb{C}^{(4)}?$

I'm just not sure if anything else apart from $\mathbb{C}$ can appear as a division ring?

Say if we looked at $\mathbb{R}G$, then we could have things like $\mathbb{H} \oplus \mathbb{H}$, $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ and so on. Where only $\mathbb{H}$, $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself can appear as division rings.

Comment: Not just division rings. Division algebras over your base field, so in the complex case there is only one possibility. Also, not all those decpmpositions are possible, just two of them.

Comment: Does a decomposition have to include $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Yes, since those copies correspond to 1-dimensional representations.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is this the case with any field $K$ such that the characteristic of $K$ doesn't divide the order of the group?